# Error 403 on writing base64 on file with php

Tags: php

I'm trying to decode a base64 string and write it to a file:

```
<?php
    // requires php5
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/images/');
    $img = $_POST['img'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

But the server gives this error message:

> **403 Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access testupload.php on this server

I have set all permissons for the php file and the images directory, so I don't understand why I get this error.

When I put the decoded string of image directly inside the `$img` variable, it works and it creates the file under the images folder... But when I try to post the decoded string it doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

NOTE :
when we try to send decoded string of image it may contain some virus or something like that from hackers ... i contact with my host providers and they say if you want we can turn of the modsecurity but its really unsafe way to do ... so what i have to do with this situation?

Comment: I don't see how this actually relates to PHP given the error doesn't seem to relate to your code, nor be produced by PHP (looks like an HTTPd error). As an aside, are you actually uploading the literal string data of an image, or are you uploading a file via a form?

Comment: @JonStirling i upload string

Comment: What are the permissions on the file? What account is your web server running under? Are there other files that do work in the same directory? Is testupload.php the file for which you've shown code? What does uniqid() return?

Comment: @JasonAller when i put the decoded string of image directly inside the $img variable it work and it create the file under images folder...but when i try to post the decoded string it dosent work

Comment: I have added that last piece of information inside your question, as it seems quite relevant. Could you add the actual code with which there is no problem, so we can really see which change makes the code fail like that?

Comment: _“When I put the decoded string of image directly inside the $img variable, it works”_ - did you still call the script using the POST method in that case, or did you switch to GET?

Comment: @misorude yes that execute correctly ... but when using post php it give error

Comment: What does the server error log say? Check with your hosting provider, whether they have anything in place that tries to block requests that have been identified as potentially “malicious” or harmful.

Comment: guys if think i found somthing ...

Comment: when we try to send decoded string of image it may contain some virus or something like that from hackers ... i contact with my host providers and they say if you want we can turn of the modsecurity but its really unsafe way to do ... so what i have to do with this situation? @misorude

Comment: Whether such data could do any harm, depends on what you actually _do_ with this data. mod_security and similar solutions just try to avoid any danger, by rejecting suspicious looking data right away, before any further processing can happen - of course that is a “blanket solution” only. But before you ask them to turn it off, I would check if you get the same problem if you send the actual image data to begin with, instead of base64 encoding it (what is the purpose of that anyway?)